# How to move multiple faces along their individual normals?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I'd like to grab multiple faces and move each one along its normal. Is there a grab individual command?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Set Transform Orientation to Normal (<kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>) and Pivot Point to Individual Origins, then hit <kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd> button twice to move along normal.

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut will do the same for individual faces, but will scale faces that are connected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work well if you have selected/connected polygons next to each other or multiple adjacent, then they move in an average vector together.

Comment: There seems to be a way to do it even for connected polygons simply using the Shrink/Fatten tool (Alt + S). Source: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148586/move-connected-vertices-along-their-individual-normal-paths

Comment: @VitKovalcik it is already in the answer, but it gives a different result.

Comment: @Denis: My mistake, I missed the part under the picture.

Comment: Works great in 2.8, too