# Move Faces along individual normals

Tags: modeling, normals, extrude

I need a way to move multiple selected faces along their individual normals. When you google for this you´ll come along this [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/how-to-move-multiple-faces-along-their-individual-normals/29120). 
This solution is working exactly the way I would need to but only on non-connected faces. As soon as the selected faces share an edge those faces will move along a single normal that seems to be the average or median of them.

I´ve seen Alt+S (Shrink/Fatten tool) being suggested but it doesnt work like intended. The normals of the moved faces will get skewed leading to a horrible looking result.

I´ve also tried every imaginable combination of Pivot points and Transform Orientations using g double z, or alt+s, extruding and Alt+e for extruding along normals.

Here´s a screenshot of what kind of result I expect on a dummy model, all of the inner walls are moved 0.1 along their respective normals from me by hand. Easy in this case because of few faces and all normals being parallel to the world.
[image]

Is there a way to do what I need?

Thanks

Comment: You could inset faces using the I key and keep the inset on the original edge. extrude as far as you want then remove doubles.

Comment: I´ve fiddled around with this but couldnt come up with anything usefull. Could you specify which Pivot Point and Transform Orientation you suggest during inner extruding and extruding?
I´ve uploaded my dummy file for anyone to try out their luck. There´s a vertex group with all the faces that need to be scale/moved/extruded.
[File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypb61zw5rw22i8o/Faces%20Along%20Normals.blend?dl=0)

Thanks

Comment: There's no easy way to do all this in one click  (unless you wanna setup a hook and constraint system for every side of exterior walls that will allow you that kind of specific control)

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean but... maybe you could try using Alt+E and select Region (Vertex Normals) to extrude along the face normals and then dissolve unwanted edges.

Comment: I know there is a way to do it. Might have been a bug because I cant repeat it. In Edit Mesh mode: I set (Pivot Point=Individual Origins) & (Orientation=Normal). Hit 'G' then 'Z'. My screen filled up with 854 blue lines (the number of faces in my mesh) and it was working. Can I do it again? NO and I'm upset about it. ;( I literally tried to do it again 15 seconds later and I couldn't. Some how, the first time, Blender saw each face as an individual selections.

Comment: [I'm trying to solve this problem with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166184/blender-python-move-faces-along-normal) If you do the faces iteratively one by one it should work.