# Move connected vertices along their individual normal paths?

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to move connected vertices along their respective normals? Similar to the way the solidify modifier works, I want to push the vertices in the directions of their normals.

With orientation=normal and origin=individual, it works as long as the vertices are not connected by an edge. Is there any way to achieve the same thing when they *are* connected? It seems the individual origins concept works based on disconnections in the mesh, like islands. I'm assuming that is why it fails to pull this off.

I appreciate any info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so apparently there is something called the shrink & fatten tool. Use Alt + S to activate it. Make sure the pivot point setting is *not* on individual origins. It looks like pretty much any other setting will work, though. Individual origins applies it onto island paths. The other modes apply it to each specific vertex path.

Hope this helps someone looking to do the same!